# having a hard time understanding this responsive css-code

Tags: css, responsive-design

so I've been trying to understand the code below but i've never seen people use css in this way.

Can someone explain what they are doing?
when and why should you use: `\ , > , < , * , +`.
Also what does the `00\25` mean etc?

If anyone who could shed some light on this I would be very thankful!
I know that I can probably find all of this in a documentation somewhere, but if **you** already possess this knowledge i would be very thankful if you could share it with me!

Here's a segment of the code.

```
    .row.\30 \25 > * {
        padding: 0 0 0 0em;
    }

    .row.\30 \25 {
        margin: 0 0 -1px 0em;
    }

    .row.uniform.\30 \25 > * {
        padding: 0em 0 0 0em;
    }

    .row.uniform.\30 \25 {
        margin: 0em 0 -1px 0em;
    }

    .row > * {
        padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
    }

    .row {
        margin: 0 0 -1px -1.5em;
    }

    .row.uniform > * {
        padding: 1.5em 0 0 1.5em;
    }

    .row.uniform {
        margin: -1.5em 0 -1px -1.5em;
    }

    .row.\32 00\25 > * {
        padding: 0 0 0 3em;
    }

    .row.\32 00\25 {
        margin: 0 0 -1px -3em;
    }

    .row.uniform.\32 00\25 > * {
        padding: 3em 0 0 3em;
    }

    .row.uniform.\32 00\25 {
        margin: -3em 0 -1px -3em;
    }

    .row.\31 50\25 > * {
        padding: 0 0 0 2.25em;
    }

    .row.\31 50\25 {
        margin: 0 0 -1px -2.25em;
    }

    .row.uniform.\31 50\25 > * {
        padding: 2.25em 0 0 2.25em;
    }

    .row.uniform.\31 50\25 {
        margin: -2.25em 0 -1px -2.25em;
    }

    .row.\35 0\25 > * {
        padding: 0 0 0 0.75em;
    }

    .row.\35 0\25 {
        margin: 0 0 -1px -0.75em;
    }

    .row.uniform.\35 0\25 > * {
        padding: 0.75em 0 0 0.75em;
    }

    .row.uniform.\35 0\25 {
        margin: -0.75em 0 -1px -0.75em;
    }
```

Here's a JSfiddle with more of the CSS:
http://jsfiddle.net/c788hvmw/

Comment: Looks like someone is using Unicode characters as class names, but I'm not so sure how `00\25` is valid CSS for anything...I'm looking into it. :)

Comment: @Purag - Thanks! Please let me know when you've found something. I also added a jsfiddle with more code!

Comment: @Purag Have you found anything? lol

Comment: Wow, what a throwback...I still have no idea what 00\25 could possibly mean, hahaha. Did you ever find out more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone explain what they are doing? when and why should you use: \ , > , < , * , +.

They are different types of [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

`>` is a child selector. An example of it use is:

```css
p {
  color: blue;
}
div > p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>This text will be blue</p>
<div>
  <p>This text will be red</p>
  <form>
    <p>This text will not be red, but blue</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

`*` is a wildcard selector. This will select all elements at the level it is used.

`\` is used to escape [unicode characters](http://unicode-table.com/en/), so in your code it is used to escape different percentages e.g.

```css
/* this means .row.0% */
.row.\30 \25 > * {
    padding: 0 0 0 0em;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row 0%">
  <p>Red text</p>
  <span>Red text</span>
  <br>
  default colour text
</div>
```

**Update**

> But when would it be useful to use \30\25 for instance?

It would be useful if you had a class/ID that started with a digit as CSS syntax rules don't allow this, therefore you would escape the digit. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DAC84/32tc3etc/) using your example CSS.

That being said, I would personally avoid starting with a digit unless you find yourself needed to when working on someone else's code as it's harder to read.

Comment: Thank you very much!
But when would it be useful to use \30\25 for instance?

Comment: In case you missed it, I updated the answer with further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though they are escaping characters for their css.  I'm not sure what the point of this is, but general use case would be to use quotes withing a class or id name. So you could do the following :`class="my\'classname\'"`, which can also be written `class="my\27classname\27"` where 27 is the hex value for a single quote (').  Here's a [list of the hex and ascii values](http://ascii.cl/)

Like I said, I'm not sure why someone would do this, but you can.

Some of the examples sort of make sense this way.  `.row.uniform.\35 0\25` could be translated to mean `.row.uniform.5 0%`  I'm really not sure what that would mean, but if (and I don't know too much about this) the space can be ignored it could be a row with either 50% width, or two columns—each 50%.  Here's an (older) [article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) on it.